# Python and vs or in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
choice = input('Enjoying the course? (y/n)')

while choice != "y" or choice != "n":
  choice = input("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again: ")
```

im trying to understand why the code above doesnt exit the while loop if i input 'y' or 'n', but if i change the `or` to `and` and input 'y' or 'n' the while loop exits? To my understanding it should have worked both.

In `or` case its read as

while choice is not 'y' or choice is not 'n' -> exit

just like `and`

while choice is not 'y' and choice is not 'n' -> exit

Comment: If you input `"n"` then the choice is _not "y"_ - if you input `"y"` then the choice is still _not "n"_ - so at least one of the comparisons will always be satisfied because it's "not the other".

Comment: Just use `while choice not in ("y", "n")`. It's clearer as you don't have to think about `or` and `and` anymore.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for the response but i genuinely still confused, you said " so at least one of the comparisons will always be satisfied because it's "not the other"" Well yes but should the loop exit the moment one of the OR condition is true? For ex, when i enter choice "y" then it should have exited even though the other condition (choice =! "n" is true aswell)?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `and` instead of `or`:

```py
while choice != "y" and choice != "n":
  choice = input("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again: ")
```

`choice != "y" or choice != "n"` always evaluates to True since `choice` cannot be `y` and `n` at the same time.

Comment: Your last line explains the right way the problem, +1

Answer (score 0):

```
while choice != "y" or choice != "n":
    choice = input("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again: ")
```

You want the `while` loop to repeat

> **until** `choice` equals "y" or `choice` equals "n"

So you want it to last

> **while** `choice` doesn't equal "y" **`and`** `choice` doesn't equal "n"

So the correct code in your case would be

```
while choice != "y" and choice != "n":
```

## Note

---

In Python a better practice would be writing this

```
while choice not in ("y", "n"): # Easier to understand, right?
```

Comment: the last line is the best way to handle this imo :-)

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way:
if you enter "y" on **or** operator below happens

```
while "y" != "y" or "y" != "n":
```

which translates to below

```
while False or True:
```

and its or operator so (True or False) will always be True

if you enter "y" on **and** operator below happens

```
while "y" != "y" and "y" != "n":
```

which translates to below

```
while False and True:
```

and as its and operator so (True and False) will always be False

hence you should use **and** if you want to leave the loop

Answer (score 0):

There are exactly 3 cases:

- source is 'x'
- source is 'y'
- source is something else. Not one of {'x', 'y'}.

In all of these 3 states  the OR condition holds, and therefore the loop continues.
In other words, the condition is always True, because `choice` can be only one of the two values. And therefore it is always not one of them, at least. Hence, the OR condition always holds, and the loop continues.